# Aligning 3 divs with an image

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying to align a profile image with two separate divs. I have used `inline-block` and `text-align:center`. I am having trouble controlling the position of the image div - it is pushing the other two divs down and out of alignment.

How should I control the position of the image?

```css
/* POST META */

.post-meta {
  background: #888;
  padding: 0 0%;
  border-top: 0px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom: 0px solid #ccc;
  text-align:center;
  float:none;
  margin-bottom:16px;
  height:80px;
}


.post-meta a {
  float:none;
  padding:0px;
  font-weight:normal;
}


.author-meta {
  font-size: 15px;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin:0px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px;
  float: none;
  color:#333;
  background:#ddd;
  height:50px;
}


.author_location {
    padding: 0px;
    text-transform: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #444;
    font-weight: normal;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    background:#ddd;
    height:50px;
    margin:0px;

}


.entry_author_image {
  float: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #999;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  font-weight: normal;
  background: no-repeat left center;
  background-size: 18px auto;
  margin:0px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  background:#ddd;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-meta">
  <div class="entry_author_image">
<img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/w1thsifonsi6dji/profile-image.png?raw=1" width="22" height="22"></div>
  <div class="author-meta"><a href="#">Author name</a></div>,
  <div class="author_location"><a href="#">City</a></div>
</div>
```

Codepen [here](http://codepen.io/coreysimons/pen/EjddLO)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply add `vertical-align:top;` to your author-meta and author-location classes. If you want a space at the top of the divs you can add `padding-top` or `margin-top`

codepen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vOVQBG)

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks. Out of interest, why by default was the div with the image causing the other two divs to appear lower from the top the parent div?

Comment: @coreysimons probably because they're different heights. one is 80, the other 2 are 50px. Html can be weird!

Comment: Thanks for your help Rachel.

Comment: No problem happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise you can do it like this:
http://codepen.io/pierre29177/pen/JdmejP

```
 <div id="author">
<img src="http://www.americansuburbx.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/08_059-PFOLIO_ONORATO-and-KREBS-PAG-52-53-Custom-Custom.jpg" alt="img6"/>

 <div id="meta">
 <a class="name">michael collins </a>
 <a class="book">into the grat wide open</a>
</div>
</div>


#author{
    position: fixed;

    height: 80px;
    background: #F99;
}
#author img {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    opacity: 0.7;
    margin-left:20px;
}

#author #meta a {
font-size: 10px;
text-transform: uppercase;
cursor:pointer;
margin:20px;
}

#author img, #author #meta  {   

margin-top:20px;
vertical-align:middle;
display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include an explanation of how your code differs from the OP's code, and why it solves the problem without introducing new problems.